# Yii: .htaccess and urlManager for separate backend and frontend

Tags: .htaccess, yii, frontend, backend

I'm having a hard time to configure my .htaccess and the urlManager in a Yii project to have the frontend in http://www.example.com and the backend in http://www.example.com/backend with the following folder structure. Any help is welcome. Thanks.

```
/assets
/backend
   /controllers
   /config
      main.php
   /models
   /views
/common
   /models
/protected
   /controllers
   /config
      main.php
   /models
   /views 
.htaccess
backend.php
index.php
```

**Solution:** after the great help of @bool.dev everything it's working, so I'm adding here every needed final file. In the frontend I'm using path format for the url and hiding the index.php

/backend/config/main.php

```
$backend=dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
Yii::setPathOfAlias('backend', $backend);
return array(
'basePath' => $backend,

'controllerPath' => $backend.'/controllers',
'viewPath' => $backend.'/views',
'runtimePath' => $backend.'/runtime',

...);
```

/protected/config/main.php

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /yii/example/
RewriteRule backend backend\.php [T=application/x-httpd-php]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

backend.php

```
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../yii/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/backend/config/main.php';
require_once($yii);
Yii::setPathOfAlias('common', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'common');
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

index.php

```
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../yii/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';
require_once($yii);
Yii::setPathOfAlias('common', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'common');
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

Comment: can you tell me why didn't you make backend a module?

Comment: I wanted to follow the directory structure of the Yii project site http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/155/the-directory-structure-of-the-yii-project-site/ described by Qiang.

Comment: shouldn't you have a separate htaccess for backend, inside the backend folder?, say make the outer htaccess for example.com , and create another htaccess inside backend, for example.com/backend

Comment: my last comment might be irrelevant. so your main concern is how to map/route example.com/backend to the folder 'backend'?

Comment: Yeah, exactly, I have the two entry scripts: `index.php` for the frontend and `backend.php` for the backend. Inside of the folder backend and protected I have `.htaccess` with `deny from all`.

Comment: an interesting problem this, if you can write .htaccess rule to route example.com/backend to backend.php, then it should be easy to do the rest from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this wiki article by Qiang](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/33/), you could make the following changes and it should work:

```
// backend.php:
require('path/to/yii.php');
Yii::createWebApplication('backend/config/main.php')->run();
```

Then in your backend's config (i.e *backend/config/main.php*):

```
$backend=dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$frontend=dirname($backend);
Yii::setPathOfAlias('backend', $backend);

return array(
    'basePath' => $backend,

    'controllerPath' => $backend.'/controllers',
    'viewPath' => $backend.'/views',
    'runtimePath' => $backend.'/runtime',

    'import' => array(
        'backend.models.*',
    ),
    // ... other configurations ...
);
```

But for this to work we need the main .htaccess to route example.com/backend to backend.php, which i haven't figured out yet.

**Edit:**
Just figured out:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projectroot/
RewriteRule backend backend\.php [T=application/x-httpd-php]
```

The `RewriteBase` was important for me, as the *backend.php* was not found when i hadn't given the correct *projectroot*, basically it should be the directory where you have the entry script *backend.php*.

Comment: Nothing so far, that guide was the first I tryed to follow but there is no way to get it to work...

Comment: actually i tried with your directory structure, and it worked, so can you tell me the exact errors? or problems that you are getting?

Comment: Do you have just that three lines in the .htaccess?

Comment: yes but depending on the errors you see, you could try and add more like `Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks`, if you tell me the error, then we could try something

Comment: So like this if I'm going to `example.com/backend` I get `Unable to resolve the request "site/error".(C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php:280)` and if I'm going to `example.com` the home page is ok but with any other link I get `404 object not found`

Comment: this could be happening if you do not have a SiteController.php inside _backend/controllers_ folder which is the default controller, as you might know, please get back to me about that. if you have .htaccess setup as i have, then backend.php entry script will get called, and its(backend's) default controller will be called

Comment: Ok, found it, folder controllers in the backend was named controller. So now the only problem is the `404 object not found` in the frontend, does it have something to do with urlManager? Thanks.

Comment: it could be, but you should also double check the generated links that you are clicking, are they correct? if yes then definitely something to do with urlManager

Comment: Yeah, they are the same links I had before adding the backend and changing the .htaccess

Comment: why don't you comment your entire .htaccess (or rename it),(basically disable it) and see how it works (the frontend). if it works properly, then we know it's an htaccess problem, otherwise could be urlManager problem. show your urlManager and htaccess code also.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11569/discussion-between-puigcerber-and-bool-dev)